# TImestamp Apps First DateEntered freeze

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Hi I want to show Onlt The first date entered, so whenever someone change it
the timestamp WONT change
what can i use for it? like filter?
my code is like this
if C&E&F is filled
then timestamp
*the timestamp should be freezed once someone input it, when someone change it the timestamp WONT CHANGET*

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const editedRange = e.range
  const sheet = editedRange.getSheet()
  var row = editedRange.getRow();

  if (
    sheet.getName() === 'Data' && ///cari sheet yang dipakai
    (editedRange.getColumn() == 4 || editedRange.getColumn() == 5 || editedRange.getColumn() == 6) && ///jika keisi
    (sheet.getRange(row, 4).getValue() !== "" && sheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue() !== "" && sheet.getRange(row, 6).getValue() !=="") ///jika tidak diisi
    )

   {
    const timestampRange = sheet.getRange(editedRange.getRow(), 1, editedRange.getNumRows(), 1)
    timestampRange.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")); /// memunculkan timestamp pada colum ke1/A yg dituju
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought you don't want the timestamp to change once you get a change in either d, e or f.

Comment: Perhaps you should add some examples of what you want.  It's not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version requires that all three of d,e and f must be filled in order to get a time stamp and once you get a timestamp then it does not change unless the user changes it manually

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry1");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet()
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart > 3 && e.range.columnStart < 7 && e.value) {
    let x = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,4,1,3).getValues()[0].every(e => e );//This requires d,e and f to be filled or truthy
    //e.source.toast("outer gate " + x);
    if (sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue() == ''  &&  x) {
      //e.source.toast("inner gate")
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d/MM/yyy HH:mm:ss"))
    }
  }//if column is null the set the timestamp otherwise do nothing
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: i already did those where column null timestamp do nothing,
but what can i do when someone change the column but make the timestamp dont change?

Comment: What do you when someone change the column

Comment: when someone change the column, i want the first entered timestamp NOT changed
i already try some from this forumn but so far havent found it yet

Comment: Try this new version and let me know

Comment: thankyou cooper it help me a lot, can you tell me how and where did you find it? i wsnt to read it

Comment: I didn't find it, I created it.  It just took me a while to figure out what you were asking for.  That is the value of knowing something about javascript because it's really the every method of arrays that solved the problem for me.